# ICMP Data Field Modified - What does it Mean?

Tags: network-monitoring, wireshark, icmp

Normal ICMP Data fields are composed of a pretty standard 32 byte string of alphabet characters.

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwabcdefghi
```

I have captured a series of ICMP echo requests using WireShark with a modified Data field and I have no idea what it means.  (Underscores represent spaces.)

```
abcdefghijklmnopprstuvwxyzabcdefghi

abcdefghijklmnoparstuvwxyzabcdefghi

__abcdefghijklmnopsrstuvwxyzabcdefghi

__abcdefghijklmnopsrstuvwxyzabcdefghi

__abcdefghijklmnopwrstuvwxyzabcdefghi

__abcdefghijklmnopdrstuvwxyzabcdefghi__
```

Note:

- The position of the "q" character
- The addition of "xyz"
- The addition of spaces before and after the payload
- When you look at the position of "q" horizontally it spells "passwd" which is a Linux/Unix command for changing a users password.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do the echoes come from your source system, or from a remote system?

Comment: This is actually an assignment from class, so we're given a packet capture file, basically no details and asked generically "whats going on here?"  I've submitted an answer resembling what syneticon-dj posted, but the professor has been rejecting basically all answers with short unhelpful responses like "think harder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard which would define what data an ICMP echo request / reply packet has to carry, so any implementation might do what it wants to. There even are implementations of ICMP echo packets as a [covert channel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICMP_tunnel). Find out, who or what is sending the packets in question, it should help you deduce the "why".

Comment: This is what he was asking us for but every time I said "ICMP Tunneling" the professor would respond "No" or give some generic answer like "Think harder."  Turns out I was right all along.